# c# - insert new data from datagridview without textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql

Is it possible to modify this update code to run insert commands to mysql? if there is, can I get some help? I'm planning to use the blank rows in `DataGridView` to insert new data.

```
private void updateTable(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable changes = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges();

    if (changes != null)
    {
        MySqlCommandBuilder mcb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);
        mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Update(changes);
        ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the mcb.GetInsertCommand()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this, but this requires a textbox though.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PointOfSale
{
    public partial class Users : Form
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapt;
        int ID = 0;
        private string conn;
        private MySqlConnection connect;

        public Users()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DisplayData();
        }

        private void db_connection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn = "Server=localhost;Database=phvpos;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
                connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                connect.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        //Insert Data  
        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (txtName.Text != "" && txtPassword.Text != "" && txtUsertype.Text != "")
            {
                db_connection();

                cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into accounts(username, password, usertype) values(@name,@password,@usertype)", connect);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", txtUsertype.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully");
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");
            }
        }
        //Display Data in DataGridView  
        private void DisplayData()
        {
            db_connection();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from accounts", connect);
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            connect.Close();
        }
        //Clear Data  
        private void ClearData()
        {
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = "";
            ID = 0;
        }
        //dataGridView1 RowHeaderMouseClick Event  
        private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            txtName.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtPassword.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txtUsertype.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }
        //Update Record  
        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db_connection();
            if (txtName.Text != "" && txtPassword.Text != "" && txtUsertype.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new MySqlCommand("update accounts set username=@name,password=@password,usertype=@usertype where userid=@userid", connect);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", txtUsertype.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
                connect.Close();
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");
```

Comment: How is this an accepted answer if the questions specifically says "without text boxes"?